# Opening a file with foreign characters in filename

Tags: java, file, character

I am developing a small application for my exam next month. In this application, users can upload files which will match their names.

Unfortunately, in Denmark, we have a few foreign characters (ÆØÅæøå), and my code will not open files containing these.

Is there a workaround which'll allow me to use these filenames?

This is the code that opens up the file:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("kontrakt/" + getStuderende().getKontrakt()));
```

And the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: kontrakt/5_Bjørnen-Bjørn-kontrakt.docx doesn't exist.
at java.awt.Desktop.checkFileValidation(Desktop.java:209)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:270)
at View.StuderendePanel.visKontraktBtnActionPerformed(StuderendePanel.java:382)
at View.StuderendePanel.access$1000(StuderendePanel.java:29)
at View.StuderendePanel$12.actionPerformed(StuderendePanel.java:284)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: the file name is 5_Bjørnen-Bjørn-kontrakt.docx  ??

Comment: can you list the file content in that directory?

Comment: Yes, `5_Bjørnen-Bjørn-kontrakt.docx` is the file, and is currently the only file in the directory. If I choose a name with A-Z characters only, it works just fine

Comment: What output would you get from this?: `System.out.println(new File("kontrakt").list()[0])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working in Windows. However, the OSX OS used in this topic appearantly doesn't support this.

This works fine

```
package others;

    import java.awt.Desktop;
    import java.io.File;

    public class A {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c://5_Bjørnen-Bjørn-kontrakt.docx"));

        }

    }
```

Try printing what you are getting from `getStuderende().getKontrakt()` method

Check if its same as the file you are opening.

Comment: I am running OSX and I just tried using my code on a Windows machine - it worked as intended. I guess I'll have to find a fix for OSX or just replace the characters. Thank you for your time :-)

Comment: @PatrickReck great , it worked , edit my answer if you want to add this info